# NVD3 Line Chart with View Finder

Tags: javascript, d3.js, filtering, data-visualization, nvd3.js

Anyone know if there is a way to hide the view finder, while still having the chart display a subset of the data? If I filter the data before sending it to the chart, the chart lines are skewed instead of contiguous.

I'm trying to filter on a date range subset of the data, while keeping the lines contiguous with the entire set of data.

I noticed in the source, on line 362, they filter on !d.disabled.  I'm wondering if I can hook into that somehow.  Does anyone know the proper usage pattern for this?

Answer (score 0):

The view finder is actually Square's Crossfilter found here [0] if you wanted to browse the source and view more documentation.

However, I would just set the display attribute to none in CSS of the svg containing the crossfilter and be done with it.

[image: crossfilter hidden from view with display:none set]

[0] http://square.github.io/crossfilter/